# The spinner is empty when no new object is being generated for an ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

To assign data of an `ArrayList<String> alKategorien` to a spinner `auswahl_kategorie`, I am using this snippet:

```
ad = new ArrayAdapter(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        alKategorien);
ad.setDropDownViewResource(
        android.R.layout
                .simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
auswahl_kategorie.setAdapter(ad);
```

I tried to reuse the `ArrayAdapter` by phrasing it like

```
if (ad == null) {
    ad = new ArrayAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            alKategorien);
    ad.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout
                    .simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    auswahl_kategorie.setAdapter(ad);
}
else
{
    ad.clear();
    ad.addAll(alKategorien);
    ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Yet unless ad is null, this yields an empty spinner.

How do I reuse the `ArrayAdapter` properly?

Comment: Try removed `ad.clear(); ad.addAll(alKategorien);`.

Comment: I did, same result.

Answer (score 0):

I have just made a very simple sample.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"
    android:id="@+id/bt1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 2"
    android:id="@+id/bt2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 3"
    android:id="@+id/bt3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btGetSpinnersValues"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Get Spinners Values" />

</LinearLayout>
```

item_schreiben.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/auswahl_kategorie" />

</LinearLayout>`
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private final int NO_OF_ITEMS = 3;
Button bt1, bt2, bt3, btGetSpinnersValues;
//Spinner auswahl_kategorie;
ArrayList<String> alKategorien = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<Integer> alDynamicChildren = new ArrayList();
ArrayAdapter ad;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
    bt1 = findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    bt2 = findViewById(R.id.bt2);
    bt3 = findViewById(R.id.bt3);
    btGetSpinnersValues = findViewById(R.id.btGetSpinnersValues);
    alKategorien.add("a");
    alKategorien.add("b");
    alKategorien.add("c");
    alKategorien.add("d");
    alKategorien.add("e");
    setSpinnerAdapter();
    for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_ITEMS; i++) {
        View dl_item_schreiben = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_schreiben, null);
        rootLayout.addView(dl_item_schreiben);
        alDynamicChildren.add(rootLayout.indexOfChild(dl_item_schreiben));
        TextView textView = dl_item_schreiben.findViewById(R.id.tvSample);
        textView.setText("Spinner " + (i + 1));
        Spinner auswahl_kategorie = dl_item_schreiben.findViewById(R.id.auswahl_kategorie);
        auswahl_kategorie.setAdapter(ad);
        auswahl_kategorie.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
    }

    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            alKategorien.clear();
            alKategorien.add("A");
            alKategorien.add("B");
            alKategorien.add("C");
            alKategorien.add("D");
            alKategorien.add("E");
            ad.notifyDataSetChanged();// or setSpinnerAdapter();
        }
    });
    bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            alKategorien.clear();
            alKategorien.add("1");
            alKategorien.add("2");
            alKategorien.add("3");
            alKategorien.add("4");
            alKategorien.add("5");
            ad.notifyDataSetChanged();// or setSpinnerAdapter();
        }
    });
    bt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            alKategorien = new ArrayList<>();
            alKategorien.add("A");
            alKategorien.add("B");
            alKategorien.add("C");
            alKategorien.add("D");
            alKategorien.add("E");
            setSpinnerAdapter();
        }
    });
    btGetSpinnersValues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String msg = "";
            LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) view.getParent();
            for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_ITEMS; i++) {
                Spinner auswahl_kategorie = parent.getChildAt(alDynamicChildren.get(i)).findViewById(R.id.auswahl_kategorie);
                msg += "Spinner " + (i +1) + ": " + auswahl_kategorie.getSelectedItem().toString() + "\n";
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

private void setSpinnerAdapter() {
    if (ad == null) {
        ad = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, alKategorien);
        ad.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //auswahl_kategorie.setAdapter(ad);
    } else {
        //ad.clear();
        //ad.addAll(alKategorien);
        ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

I tested the code and spinner changed content for bt1/bt2 clicked. But after bt3 clicked, no more change.

First, when the adapter is created, it is set with **alKategorien** as the data list, so call `ad.clear()` just clear **alKategorien** and `ad.addAll(alKategorien);` add back an empty list. Therefore those two lines should be removed.

Second, data list **cannot** be created again (i.e. `= new ArrayList<>()` and so no more change after bt3 clicked) but can be modified (clear, add, remove) because it acts like a linkage between activity and adapter. If data list is created again by **new**, then the adapter needs to be created again as linkage broken. There may be other conditions that can break the linkage. Since the code that I mentioned in first point is removed, so issue should be caused by the way of modifying data list which is not shown in the snippet.

Comment: I should note that I have the same spinner in different layouts, so I use for instance `View dl_item_schreiben = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_schreiben, null);` and `Spinner auswahl_kategorie = dl_item_schreiben.findViewById(R.id.auswahl_kategorie);`. Do I need to create a separate `ad` for each layout even though the spinners have the same content?

Comment: 1 adapter can handle multiple spinners. I edited the code to show this.